# I have this array from Matlab. I couldn't create a matrix like it using mathematica. I need help please

Tags: education

N=1000;

v0=1;

v=v0.*ones(1,N+1);

% first well
for i=341:460
v(i)=0;
end

% second well
for i=540:659
v(i)=0;
end

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica does not have `ones` command

> ```
> ones(N) is an N-by-N matrix of ones.
>
> ones(M,N) or ones([M,N]) is an M-by-N matrix of ones.
>
> ones(M,N,P,...) or ones([M N P ...]) is an M-by-N-by-P-by-... array of
> ones.
>
> ones(SIZE(A)) is the same size as A and all ones.
> ```

But `Table` could be used in its place. So this code

```
N=20;
v0=1;
v=v0.*ones(1,N+1);

for i=3:4
v(i)=0; 
end

for i=10:15
v(i)=0; 
end

>> v

v =    
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1

>> size(v)

ans =

     1    21
```

becomes in Mathematica as

```
n=20;
v0=1;
v=v0*Table[1,{1},{n+1}];
v[[1,3;;4]]=0;
v[[1,10;;15]]=0;
```

gives

```
{{1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}

Dimensions[v]
(* {1, 21} *)
```

> but how can these points be plotted with another variable, for
> example, x

The `ListPlot` command can be used to plot list of points.

```
ListPlot[v]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See help for additional options.

> but I want to plot this function Cos[x v], can you help me? v={{1, 1,
> 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}} no 3d put 2d
> for different areas v

I am not sure if this is what is wanted.

```
MapThread[Plot[#1, {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"v=", #2}]] &, 
 Flatten[{Cos[x*v], v}, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much, but how can these points be plotted with another variable, for example, x ?

Comment: @MohammedOmran I've updated the post for the plot.

Comment: Thank you, @Nasser, but I want to plot this function Cos[x v], can you help me? v={{1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}} no 3d put 2d for different areas v

Comment: @MohammedOmran I've updated the post for the second plot. But I am not sure if I understood what you want.

Comment: @MohammedOmran Mathematica is not Matlab: just as Java is not Python. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) by the inventor would help you get started.

Comment: mass = 0.007;
hbar = 1.054571596; 
hbar2 = hbar^2;
echarge = 1.602176462; 
baremass = 9.10938188; 
const1 = hbar2/baremass/echarge; 
const = const1/mass;

Comment: TISE1D[U_Function, {xmin_, xmax_}, N0Grid_ : 101, 
  BoundaryCondition_String : "zero"] := 
 Module[{ \[CapitalDelta]x = (xmax - xmin)/(N0Grid - 1), Hmtx, Tmtx, 
   Vmtx}, Tmtx = -const SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> -2, {i_, j_} /; 
        Abs[i - j] == 1 -> 1}, {N0Grid, N0Grid}];
  Vmtx = DiagonalMatrix[U /@ Range[xmin, xmax, \[CapitalDelta]x]];
  Hmtx = Tmtx + Vmtx;
  If[BoundaryCondition == "periodic", 
   Hmtx[[1, -1]] = Hmtx[[-1, 1]] = -const;];
  Sort[Transpose@Eigensystem[Hmtx], (#1[[1]] < #2[[1]]) &]]

Comment: V1 = {{0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}};
 TISE1D[Function[{x}, V1], {0, 10}, 5][[1 ;; 4, 2]] // MatrixForm             How can you put v in this code if it is a vector?

Comment: @MohammedOmran Comments should not be used for new questions.